# Scrape google's all search results based on certain criteria?

Tags: c#, web-crawler, web-scraping

I am working on my mapper and I need to get the full map of newegg.com

I could try to scrap NE directly (which kind of violates NE's policies), but they have many products that are not available via direct NE search, but only via google.com search; and I need those links too.

Here is the search string that returns 16mil of results:
https://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=.com%2FProduct%2FProduct.aspx%3FItem%3D&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=newegg.com&as_occt=url&safe=off&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=

I want my scraper to go over all results and log hyperlinks to all these results.
I can scrap all the links from google search results, but google has limit of 100 pages for each query- 1,000 results and again, google is not happy with this approach. :)

I am new to this; Could you advise / point me in the right direction ? Are there any tools/methodology that could help me to achieve my goals?

Comment: Scraping Google results is also against their T&C.

Comment: I don't know why you would see that as hypocrisy. Scraping their results is effectively going to give the scrapper the benefit of google's intellectual property...and if you were going to use that to generate search results... It's likely to protect themselves from  their competitors taking advantage of their own hard work. .

Comment: @Rig, I totally understand Google's **business motivations**, but I find that practice hypocritical when it's coming from a company that built its business on initially being able to crawl other web sites indiscriminately. Google practically forces you to let them crawl your site: if you don't, then you're *metaphorically* going to the "internet jail" and your website will never see the light of day; however, if you want to crawl Google, then it's a "no no." Again, **I don't promote that one should violate the T&C**, I just think they've been straying from their "do no evil mentality."

Comment: My original comment disappeared... pretty sure I didn't delete it either.

Comment: Check my answer on how to scrape Google here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22703153/1190665 . It is based on the open source php scraper at http://scraping.compunect.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am new to this; Could you advise / point me in the right direction ?
>   Are there any tools/methodology that could help me to achieve my
>   goals?

Google takes a lot of steps to prevent you from crawling their pages and I'm not talking about merely asking you to abide by their robots.txt. I don't agree with their ethics, nor their T&C, not even the *"simplified"* version that they pushed out (but that's a separate issue).

If you want to be seen, then **you have to let google crawl your page;** however, if you want to crawl Google then you have to jump through some major hoops! Namely, you have to get a bunch of proxies so you can get past the rate limiting and the 302s + captcha pages that they post up any time they get suspicious about your "activity."

**Despite being thoroughly aggravated about Google's T&C, I would NOT recommend that you violate it!** However, if you *absolutely need to get the data*, then you can get a big [list of proxies](http://proxy-list.org/en/index.php), load them in a queue and pull a proxy from the queue each time you want to get a page. If the proxy works, then put it back in the queue; otherwise, discard the proxy. Maybe even give a counter for each failed proxy and discard it if it exceeds some number of failures.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but you can use [googles custom search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/). Of course, its starts to cost money after 100 searches a day. I guess they must be running a business ;p

Comment: Does this really provide you with google search results?  It appears from first glance to only provide you results relevant to a custom google search you've configured, such as one for your own website...

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late but I think it is worth to mention that you can professionally scrape Google reliable and not cause problems with it.

Actually it is not of any threat I know about to scrape Google.
It is cahllenging if you are unexperienced but I am not aware about a single case of legal consequence and I am always following this topic.

Maybe one of the largest cases of scraping happened some years ago when Microsoft scraped Google to power Bing. Google was able to proof it by placing fake results which do not exist in real world and Bing suddenly took them up.
Google named and shamed them, that's all that happened as far as I remember.

Using the API is rarely ever a real use, it costs a lot of money to use it for even a small amount of results and the free amount is rather small (40 lookups per hour before ban).
The other downside is that the API does not mirror the real search results, in your case maybe less a problem but in most cases people want to get the real ranking positions.

Now if you do not accept Googles TOS or ignore it (they did not care about your TOS when they scraped you in their startup) you can go another route.
Mimic a real user and get the data directly from the SERPs.

The clue here is to send around 10 requests per hour (can be increased to 20) with each IP address (yes you use more than one IP). That amount has proven to cause no problem with Google over the past years.
Use caching, databases, ip rotation management to avoid hitting it more often than required.
The IP addresses need to be clean, unshared and if possible without abusive history.
The originally suggested proxy-list would complicate the topic a lot as you receive unstable, unreliable IPs with questionable absuive use, share and history.

There is an open source PHP project on http://scraping.compunect.com which contains all the features you need to start, I used it for my work which now runs for some years without troubles.
Thats a finished project which is mainly built to be used as customizable base of your project but runs standalone too.

Also PHP is not a bad choice, I originally was sceptical but I was running PHP (5) as background process for two years without a single interruption.
The performance is easily good enough for such a project so I would give it a shot.
Otherwise, PHP code is like C/JAVA .. you can see how things are done and repeat them in your own project.