# How to fix C# google search

Tags: c#

So I'm creating a program that can go into google and search for the word that has
been saved into a variable. So my question is how I can do this, without having it go to a URL instead just going to Google and search "whatever" Here's the code.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Script.Text == Script.Text)
        {
            Console.AppendText("\n[1] Loading Websites of " + Script.Text + "...");
        }
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "Scripts " + Script.Text);
    }
```

Comment: WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 

is not required if you use Process.Start().

just put params in there as ( "Location of chrome.exe", "Your Target WebURL" ); for that

Comment: I know that, but that is for a future statement that I will add in. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: How about consuming [Google CustomSearch API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/customsearch/v1)....?

Comment: Advices that explicitly violate TOC of sites are questionable... So I strongly recommend to perform your own research about "C# scrape google search" and read answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773724/scrape-googles-all-search-results-based-on-certain-criteria. (Which also allow you to demonstrate you own research in the question which currently lacks that information)

Comment: So, you want to open a web browser with that search term prefilled? If so, use `https://www.google.com?q=searchtermhere` and ensure that `searchtermhere` is url encoded.

Comment: mjwills. What I want to do is for my program to open Google.exe and then automatically search for the site that is contained in my URL, so say my Variable is  x = textBox1.Text  Process.Start("BLAHBLAHBLAH/chrome.exe", x);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open in default browser in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
String stringToSearch = “stackoverflow”;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com.au/search?q=" + stringToSearch);
```

This assumes IE is the **default browser** on your machine. If Chrome or Firefox is the default browser, then code will fail.

This is a useful link:

http://www.seirer.net/blog/2014/6/10/solved-how-to-open-a-url-in-the-default-browser-in-csharp

Maybe you can put it in a try catch block and see if there is an exception. If there is an exception with starting IE, then open chrome.

Comment: You can simply write iexplore.exe instead of the full path. And even though internet explorer is not the default browser, it still works!

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
public static void GoToSite(string url)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", url);
}
```

you can also change browser dynamically by adding a second params